# How to match the first occurrence of a pattern (IP addr) on each line of the file?

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

I have a text file (file.txt) with lines such as -

```
1234      198.18.1.1  5.6.7.8   user1   10 Gbps 32 GB -
15.2.1.2  198.18.1.2  9.10.11   user2   10 Gbps 16 GB (connected to 198.18.1.3)
and so on
```

The first octet of all IP addresses is 3 digit (eg. 198). 
How to find the first match of an IP address on each line?

**Output**

```
198.18.1.1
198.18.1.2
```

I tried -

```
grep -oE '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' file.txt
```

But that is returning -

```
198.18.1.1  
5.6.7.8
15.2.1.2  
198.18.1.2
198.18.1.3
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to first match of an IP address on each line that starts with 3 digits, one option is to use grep with `-oP` and use `{3}` for the first quantifier. Use `\K` to clear the current match buffer.

```
grep -oP '^.*?\b\K[0-9]{3}(?:\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}\b' file.txt
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EE54lJ/1) | [grep demo](https://tio.run/##TcuxDoIwEAbg3ae4rWDkwrWC1IXEhcHF3WpioZGJEoqT8uy1qIlcbrj77z59c633pm4tMOJiC58iWSCFRgLIMMcdFiF9ODPQfE2h0r0DwaE6QLKiDHn45QsXZomUItHP8YWjfHZRbbvO1KNpYLR/KWIGL7gPpofEnoBdcV0qrY7nNJGXp5iicq/wu9BGTHGIlGbevwE)

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `.*?\b` Match any char as least as possible, word boundary to prevent the word being part of a longer match
- `\K` Clear the match buffer
- `[0-9]{3}(?:\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}\b` Match an ip like pattern, starting with 3 digits using `{3}`

Output

```
198.18.1.1
198.18.1.2
```

Comment: @GillesQuenot Where do you see a lookaround? I see that you changed it to `{3}` though..

Comment: `\K` is a _look-around_ shortcut

Comment: If you don't use `\K` you will get other matches as well

Answer (score 0):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

```
perl -lne 'print $& if /\d{3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/' file
```

If you insist to use [grep](/questions/tagged/grep):

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    grep -oP -m1 '[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' <<< "$line"
done < file.txt
```

### Output:

```
198.18.1.1
198.18.1.2
```

Comment: thanks, but the IP address i want to extract have 3 digits in the first octet. Here, 15.2.1.2 is a version no. I would appreciate if we can do this using linux commands. Thanks.

Comment: So use the 'grep' version. Edited to match first octet with 3 digits

Comment: Also need the "198.18.1.2" from the second line. Thanks